# Determine if any of the default AutoFilter criteria have been unchecked

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I've a workbook that contains multiple sheets where the AutoFilters are enabled. The workbook is shared however. I want to show a messageBox informing the user that if they have unchecked any of the Filter Criteria they need to recheck it before closing the workbook. We are trying to prevent the users from saving out modified filter settings. Unfortunately since this is a shared workbook I cannot reset the AutoFilter upon workbook.close.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem? What where the problems you met?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to check if any of the sheets are actually filtered-as opposed to simply having the filters in place-then you need to test the Filtermode property